# Navigo.js only works on localhost

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application, client-side

I'm trying to build routes for my SPA, and the problem is that when I use `localhost:3000` the routes work just fine. It works just as it suppose to. But if the URL is `127.0.0.1:8000` or `domain.com/route` it doesn't work.

For `localhost:3000` I'm using a npm module `lite-server` and for `127.0.0.1:8000` I'm using the npm module `local-web-server`. The library that I'm using for routing is [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo).

Multiple routes: [Example](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo#adding-multiple-routes)

Tried the demo provided, still no luck. Searched the internet, there are no Stack Overflow question about client-side routing, only for the backend.

The route code:

```
var routes = new Navigo(null);

    // Main
    routes.on(() => {
        console.log('Default route');
    });

    // Other routes
    routes.on({
        '/route1': () => {
            console.log('route1');
        },
        '/route2': () => {
            console.log('route2');
        }
    }).resolve();

    // 404
    routes.notFound(() => {
        console.log(404);
    }).resolve();
```

Only the **Default route** works, the rest of them are ignored.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me on 127.0.0.1 or other domain.

```
const dummyTarget = document.querySelector('div'); // <-- Dummy target to fake navigation

// Initial Navigo
var root = null;
var useHash = true; // Defaults to: false
var hash = '#!'; // Defaults to: '#'
var router = new Navigo(root, useHash, hash);

router
    .on({
      '/': () => { // This is actually the route
        dummyTarget.innerHTML = `I'm on home page`;

      },
      '/another': () => {
        dummyTarget.innerHTML = 'Now on second page';
      }
    })
    .resolve();
```

Result:
[image]